# AFTER adding a style resource file got Android resource linking failed

Tags: android, build, linker, resources

After I´ve created a style in my application which uses a gridlayout, build is not working anymore.

I´ve tried Invalidate Caches & restart, and change some gradle dependencies, but since I don´t understand what´s going on, I could not fix it.

the design was working ok without the style resource file, after I´ve created it for the buttons, the build start to fail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
app:columnCount="2"
app:rowCount="4"
app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button  style="@style/MainButton"
    android:id="@+id/b_1"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_row="0"
    android:text="@string/boletim"
    android:onClick="OnClick"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_boletim"         />
<Button
    style="@style/MainButton"
    android:id="@+id/b_2"
    app:layout_column="1"
    app:layout_row="0"

    android:text="@string/salarios"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_salario"         />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

this is my button resource file, which is created in the values folder

```
<resources>
<!-- estilo do botão -->
<style name="MainButton" >
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#141210</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24dp</item>
    <item name="layout_columnWeight">1</item>
    <item name="layout_rowWeight">1</item>
    <item name="layout_gravity">fill_horizontal|fill_vertical</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

and perhaps this is usefull too, some build.gradle infos

```
compileSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 27
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"      minSdkVersion 23

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3' }

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0- 
   beta1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found the solution:
in the gradle app properties file the compile versionarget and build must match: 
   compileSdkVersion 28 and  targetSdkVersion 28 and    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'